# Cordova/Phonegap SQL data inserts duplicated

Tags: cordova

I'm building a small test app with Cordova/Phonegap 2.2.0

The app initialises and populates a database with 5 records. Each INSERT is carried out via a function and the function is called from a loop so that I can vary the number of records easily. For testing purposes a logical condition decides whether the record's id is odd or even and then populates a detail field with an appropriate string. I should therefore have 5 records inserted with details as follows:

```
(id) (detail)
(1)  (This record is odd)
(2)  (This record is even)
(3)  (This record is odd)
(4)  (This record is even)
(5)  (This record is odd)
```

However, when I retrieve data for either an individual record, or for all records I always get 'This record is odd' for the detail:

```
(1)  (This record is odd)
(2)  (This record is odd)
(3)  (This record is odd)
(4)  (This record is odd)
(5)  (This record is odd)
```

If I change the loop to insert 6 records then all my results show 'This record is even'

So it's as though the last inserted detail value is being applied to all records. Either that or I'm not processing the result set properly.

Example code below if anyone can help.

Many thanks

```js
// Create a reference to the database
function getDatabase() {
    return window.openDatabase("productDB", "1.0", "Product Database", 200000);

// Run the onDeviceReady method
onDeviceReady();
populateDatabase();

// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    db = getDatabase();
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF  EXISTS products');
    }, databaseError);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, product_text)');
    }, databaseError);
}

// Run a select statement to pull out all records
function getAllItems() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM products', [], queryAllSuccess, databaseError);
    }, databaseError);
}

// Process the SQLResultSet
function queryAllSuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var output = '';
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        output = output + '<h2> ID ' + results.rows.item(i).id + '</h2>';
        output = output + '<p>' + results.rows.item(i).product_text + '</p>';
    }
    messageElement.html(output);
}

// Populate the database
function populateDatabase() {
    for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
      insertProductItem(i);
    }                            
}

// Insert record into the database
function insertProductItem(itemId) {
    if ( itemId % 2) {
        var productText = "<p>Item " + itemId + " - This is an odd record</p>";
    } else {
        var productText = "<p>Item " + itemId + " - This is an even record</p>";
    }
    sql = 'INSERT INTO products (product_text) VALUES ("' + productText + '")';
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sql);
    },databaseError);
}
```

Comment: Please note that I have fixed this. The issue was with the concatenation of the string to be inserted. I have changed to use a placeholder as follows:


    sql = 'INSERT INTO products (product_text) VALUES (?)';
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sql, [productText]);
    },databaseError);

Answer (score 0):

You must be messing with the insert statement, please check the insert syntax in detail [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Please try following code:

```
// Insert record into the database
function insertProductItem(itemId) {
    if ( itemId % 2) {
        var productText = "<p>Item " + itemId + " - This is an odd record</p>";
    } else {
        var productText = "<p>Item " + itemId + " - This is an even record</p>";
    }
    sql = 'INSERT INTO products (product_text) VALUES (?)'; 
    db.transaction(function(tx) { tx.executeSql(sql, [productText]); },
       databaseError);
    }
```